# Zf2 and doctrine model implementation

Tags: php5, zend-framework, doctrine

I've implemented for the first time Doctrine-ORM on my SOAP server application; can you tell me if I could optimize some of the written ORM-related code?

More specifically, is it a good practice to package entities in sub-namespaces, or is it better to simply put them in an Entity namespace ?

I cannot post the XML used for parsing as it is too long, but it isn't the concern.

**Soap serve method**

```
/**
 * @param string $apiKey
 * @param $id
 * @return mixed
 * @throws \Doctrine\ORM\ORMException
 * @throws \Doctrine\ORM\OptimisticLockException
 * @throws \Doctrine\ORM\TransactionRequiredException
 */
public function getProductConfig($apiKey, $id)
{
    /** @var Response $response */

    // check credentials
    $response = $this->checkCredentials($apiKey);
    if ($response->getSuccess()) {

        // call api
        $response = $this->api->getProductDetails($id);
        if ($response->getSuccess()) {

            $responseCode = self::RESPONSE_OK;

            // populate database
            if ($response->product) {

                if (!$product = $this->em->find('Application\Entity\Prduct', $response->product->id)) {
                    $product = new Entity\Product();
                    $product->setId($response->product->id);
                }

                $product->setType($response->product->type)
                    ->setName($response->product->name)
                    ->setStock($response->product->stock)
                    ->setDescription($response->product->description);

                $this->em->persist($product);
                $this->em->flush();

                if ($product->getId() && $response->config) {
                    foreach ($response->config as $data) {

                        if (!$config = $this->em->find('Application\Entity\Product\Configuration', $data->id)) {
                            $config = new Entity\Product\Configuration();
                            $config->setId($data->id);
                        }

                        $config->setName($data->name)
                            ->setDescription(trim($data->description) ?: null)
                            ->setCategory($data->category)
                            ->setDontChargeDefault($data->config->dontchargedefault)
                            ->setInitialValue($data->config->initialval)
                            ->setLowValue($data->config->minvalue)
                            ->setHighValue($data->config->maxvalue)
                            ->setProduct($product);

                        $this->em->persist($config);
                    }
                    $this->em->flush();
                }
            } else {
                $responseCode = self::RESPONSE_ERROR;
            }

            // create new response from subcall
            $response = new Response(array(
                'call' => __FUNCTION__,
                'code' => $responseCode
            ));
        }
    }

    return $this->handleResponse($response);
}
```

**Product model (have many configurations)**

```
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection;

/**
 * Product entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="Products")
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @package Application\Entity
 */
class Product
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    protected $id;

    /** @ORM\Column(type="integer") */
    protected $type;

    /** @ORM\Column(type="string") */
    protected $name;

    /** @ORM\Column(type="integer") */
    protected $stock;

    /** @ORM\Column(type="text") */
    protected $description;

    /**
     * @var Collection
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Application\Entity\Product\Configuration", mappedBy="product", fetch="LAZY")
     */
    protected $configurations;

    /**
     * Constructor
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->configurations = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    /**
     * @return Collection
     */
    public function getConfigurations()
    {
        return $this->configurations;
    }

    /**
     * Get id
     * @return integer
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set product Id
     * @param int $id
     * @return Product
     */
    public function setId($id)
    {
        $this->id = (int)$id;
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get product description
     * @return string
     */
    public function getDescription()
    {
        return $this->description;
    }

    /**
     * Set product description
     * @param string $description
     * @return Product
     */
    public function setDescription($description)
    {
        $this->description = $description;
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get product name
     * @return string
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    /**
     * Set product name
     * @param string $name
     * @return Product
     */
    public function setName($name)
    {
        $this->name = $name;
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get product stock availability
     * @return int
     */
    public function getStock()
    {
        return $this->stock;
    }

    /**
     * Set product stock availability
     * @param int $stock
     * @return Product
     */
    public function setStock($stock)
    {
        $this->stock = $stock;
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get product type
     * @return int
     */
    public function getType()
    {
        return $this->type;
    }

    /**
     * Set product type id
     * @param int $type
     * @return Product
     */
    public function setType($type)
    {
        $this->type = (int)$type;
        return $this;
    }
}
```

**product configuration (belongs to one product)**

```
<?php namespace Application\Entity\Product;

use Application\Entity\Product;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use InvalidArgumentException;

/**
 * Product config entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="ProductsConfigurations")
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @package Application\Entity\Product
 */
class Configuration
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    protected $id;

    /** @ORM\Column(type="string") */
    protected $name;

    /** @ORM\Column(type="string", nullable=true) */
    protected $description;

    /** @ORM\Column(type="string") */
    protected $category;

    /** @ORM\Column(type="integer") */
    protected $lowValue;

    /** @ORM\Column(type="integer") */
    protected $highValue;

    /** @ORM\Column(type="integer") */
    protected $initialValue;

    /** @ORM\Column(type="boolean") */
    protected $dontChargeDefault;

    /**
     * @var Product the product this configuration belongs to
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Application\Entity\Product", inversedBy="configurations")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="productId", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    protected $product;

    /**
     * @return Product
     */
    public function getProduct()
    {
        return $this->product;
    }

    /**
     * Sets a new user group and cleans the previous one if set
     * @param Product $product
     * @return Configuration
     * @throws InvalidArgumentException
     */
    public function setProduct($product)
    {
        if ($product === null) {
            if ($this->product !== null) {
                $this->product->getConfigurations()->removeElement($this);
            }
            $this->product = null;
        } else {
            if (!$product instanceof Product) {
                throw new InvalidArgumentException(sprintf(
                    '$product must be null or instance of Product, %s given',
                    get_class($product)
                ));
            }

            if ($this->product !== null) {
                $this->product->getConfigurations()->removeElement($this);
            }
            $this->product = $product;
            $product->getConfigurations()->add($this);
        }

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get id
     * @return integer
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set config Id
     * @param int $id
     * @return Configuration
     */
    public function setId($id)
    {
        $this->id = (int)$id;
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get config category
     * @return string
     */
    public function getCategory()
    {
        return $this->category;
    }

    /**
     * Set config category
     * @param string $category
     * @return Configuration
     */
    public function setCategory($category)
    {
        $this->category = $category;
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get description
     * @return string
     */
    public function getDescription()
    {
        return $this->description;
    }

    /**
     * Set description
     * @param string $description
     * @return Configuration
     */
    public function setDescription($description)
    {
        $this->description = $description;
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get don't charge default flag
     * @return bool
     */
    public function getDontChargeDefault()
    {
        return $this->dontChargeDefault;
    }

    /**
     * Set don't charge default flag
     * @param bool $dontChargeDefault
     * @return Configuration
     */
    public function setDontChargeDefault($dontChargeDefault)
    {
        $this->dontChargeDefault = (bool)$dontChargeDefault;
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get highest config value
     * @return int
     */
    public function getHighValue()
    {
        return $this->highValue;
    }

    /**
     * Set highest config value
     * @param int $highValue
     * @return Configuration
     */
    public function setHighValue($highValue)
    {
        $this->highValue = (int)$highValue;
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get initial config value
     * @return int
     */
    public function getInitialValue()
    {
        return $this->initialValue;
    }

    /**
     * Set initial config value
     * @param int $initialValue
     * @return Configuration
     */
    public function setInitialValue($initialValue)
    {
        $this->initialValue = (int)$initialValue;
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get config lowest value
     * @return int
     */
    public function getLowValue()
    {
        return $this->lowValue;
    }

    /**
     * Set config lowest value
     * @param int $lowValue
     * @return Configuration
     */
    public function setLowValue($lowValue)
    {
        $this->lowValue = (int)$lowValue;
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get config name
     * @return string
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    /**
     * Set config name
     * @param string $name
     * @return Configuration
     */
    public function setName($name)
    {
        $this->name = $name;
        return $this;
    }
}
```